# Number of arrangements of $n^2$ dominoes on a $2n \times 2n$ square grid

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

How many ways are there to arrange $n^2$ dominos into a $2n \times 2n$ square grid, such that in any $2 \times 2$ sub-grid, there are at least two adjacent unit squares covered by dominos? (not necessarily by the same domino).

Note: Two unit squares are called *adjacent* if they share an edge.

I was trying to look for a solution with recursive relation, but there were like too many cases to consider. Any idea?

Comment: 1. I wouldn't call this a "tiling", as not all squares are covered.  2. By a simple counting argument, each $2\times 2$ sub-grid must contain *exactly* two unit squares covered by dominos, since exactly half of squares of the grid are covered.

Comment: I think you mean each $2 \times 2$ disjoint sub-grid contain exactly two unit square if we divide the $2n \times 2n$ square grid into $n^2$ $2 \times 2$ sub-grids; not an arbitrary sub-grid. For example, for the $4 \times 4$ grid, if you put all the dominos in row 2 and row 3, the condition is still satisfied and there are 4 sub-grids with both 4 unit squares covered by dominos.